# Python AttributeError:cos

Tags: python, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve numerically an equation using Python2.7. This is the whole code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import nsolve
from scipy import *
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

# Symbols
theta = Symbol('theta')
phi = Symbol('phi')
phi0 = Symbol('phi0')
H0 = Symbol('H0')
# Constants
a = 0.05 
b = 0.05**2/(8*pi*1e-7)
c= 0.001/(4*pi*1e-7)
phi0 = 60*pi/180 
H0 = -0.03/(4*pi*1e-7)
def m(theta,phi):
    return np.array([sin(theta)*cos(phi), sin(theta)*cos(phi), cos(phi)])
def h(phi0):
    return np.array([cos(phi0), sin(phi0), 0])
def k(theta,phi,phi0):
    return np.vdot(m(theta,phi),h(phi0))
def F(theta,phi,phi0,H0): 
    return -(a*H0)*k(theta,phi,phi0)+b*(cos(theta)**2)+c*(sin(2*theta)**2)+sin(theta)**4*sin(2*phi)**2
def F_phi(theta,phi,phi0,H0):
    return simplify(diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),phi))
def G(phi):
    return F_phi(pi/2,phi,phi0,H0)
solution = nsolve(G(phi), phi)
print solution
```

and this is the traceback that I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Test.py", line 33, in <module>
solution = nsolve(G(phi), phi)
File "Test.py", line 32, in G
return F_phi(pi/2,phi,phi0,H0)
File "Test.py", line 30, in F_phi
return simplify(diff(F(theta,phi,phi0,H0),phi))
File "Test.py", line 28, in F
return -(a*H0)*k(theta,phi,phi0)+b*(cos(theta)**2)+c*(sin(2*theta)**2)+sin(theta)**4*sin(2*phi)**2
File "Test.py", line 26, in k
return np.vdot(m(theta,phi),h(phi0))
File "Test.py", line 22, in m
return np.array([sin(theta)*cos(phi), sin(theta)*cos(phi), cos(phi)])
AttributeError: cos
```

I am using the sympy, numpy and pylab libraries. So, I don't get a problem with the cos function. Any help?

Comment: Please include the full traceback; there is no attribute access here to *cause* the exception, so we are also probably missing some code.

Comment: Sorry I thought the code I included was sufficient. I edited the post to include the whole code and the traceback.

Comment: After fixing the imports the IndexError will probably disappear, because it has the same cause. If it doesn't just let me know in a comment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is using star imports instead of importing each package under a different namespace.

This imports function `sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric.cos` under the `cos` name:

```
from sympy import *
```

After that, you import `<ufunc 'cos'>` under the name `cos`, overwriting the previous definition:

```
from scipy import *
```

Then, it overwrites the previous `cos` function by another copy of exactly the same function (from the matplotlib package):

```
from pylab import *
```

This also imports the same `<ufunc 'cos'>` but under the `np.cos` name. *This is the proper way to import things*:

```
import numpy as np
```

In the end, you're left with a copy of the cos function that knows how to apply itself to floats, not sympy objects. When you try to apply that function to sympy objects like `phi` you get the `AttributeError`. All in all, the solution to this particular problem is to fix the imports and know if you want the functions from sympy or the ones from numpy.

Comment: I just kept the imports from sympy, the IndexError disappeared but I still have a problem which I will address in another post.

Answer (score 2):

Did you import the `cos` function? It's in the `math` module

```
from math import cos
```

Same thing for `sin`.

Comment: When I try to import the functions from the math module, I get almost the same traceback with this error: "File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/expr.py", line 221, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float". But when I import them from sympy, I get this: " File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 984, in diff
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range"

Comment: He imported it 4 times... (3 under the same name). After fixing that, he's left wit other problems (the IndexError), but maybe that should be a different question?