# Sympy to numpy causes the AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'cos'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sympy, derivative, lambdify

I am trying to do partial derivatives using sympy and I want to convert it to a function so that I can substitute values and estimate the derivatives at some values of t_1, t_2. The code I am using is as follows:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()
t_1,t_2,X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2,X_c1,X_c2,Y_c1,Y_c2,a_1,a_2,psi_1,psi_2,b_1,b_2= sp.symbols('t_1 t_2 X_1 X_2 Y_1 Y_2 X_c1 X_c2 Y_c1 Y_c2 a_1 a_2 psi_1 psi_2 b_1 b_2')

X_1=X_c1 + (a_1 * sp.cos(t_1) * sp.cos(psi_1)) - ((b_1) * sp.sin(t_1)* sp.sin(psi_1))

X_2=X_c2 + (a_2 * sp.cos(t_2) * sp.cos(psi_2)) - ((b_2) * sp.sin(t_2)* sp.sin(psi_2))

Y_1=Y_c1 + (a_1 * sp.cos(t_1) * sp.sin(psi_1)) + ((b_1) * sp.sin(t_1)* sp.cos(psi_1))

Y_2=Y_c2 + (a_2 * sp.cos(t_2) * sp.sin(psi_2)) + ((b_2) * sp.sin(t_2)* sp.sin(psi_2))

D=(((X_2-X_1)**2) + ((Y_2-Y_1)**2))**0.5

y_1=sp.diff(D,t_1)

y_2=sp.diff(D,t_2)

f=sp.lambdify(t_1, y_1, "numpy")

g=sp.lambdify(t_2, y_2, "numpy")
```

When I try to substitute a value for t_1 using,

```
f(np.pi/2)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f37892b21c8b> in <module>()
----> 1 f(np.pi/2)

/users/vishnu/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy    /__init__.py in <lambda>(_Dummy_23)

AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'cos'
```

I referred to the following links:

[What causes this error (AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos') in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in)

[Python AttributeError:cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336048/python-attributeerrorcos)

but I think my imports of numpy and sympy are not clashing unlike the cases mentioned in those links. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Expression `y_1` is a function of many variables, however, your `lambdify` definition implies only a single input argument (`t_1`), resulting in error. Either define the `lambdify` function as having multiple input arguments, or substitute the other symbolic variables by numbers.

Comment: Hi Stelios, thanks for replying. Is it not possible that we calculate the partial derivative treating other variables as symbols and only substitute for t_1? For example: if t_1=np.pi/2 then partial derivative of the expression 'cos(t_1)*X_c1' with respect to t_1 equals to '-X_c1'.

Comment: The notion of "symbol" as used in `Sympy` is not valid in `Numpy`. `Numpy` only understands functions with (multiple) numerical arguments. If you only need to replace `t_1` with numbers, treating the other variables as symbols, you should stick with `Sympy` (e.g., using the `subs` method)

Comment: For my complete program, I am interested to substitute values for all the variables and then calculate the derivatives. Could you please give me an example using lambdify as to how I could substitute for all variables and then use numpy? Is it simply f=sp.lambdify(t_1,X_c1,a_1,b_1,.....  , y_1, "numpy")

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of error occurs when you call `np.cos(a_symbol)`, which apparently translates under-the-hood in numpy to `a_symbol.cos()`.

`lambdify` is for numeric calculations - it replaces all `sp` calls with `np` calls. But what you're doing is symbolic. This is enough for your problem:

```
f1 = lambda t: y_1.subs({t_1: t})
f2 = lambda t: y_2.subs({t_2: t})
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question correctly. Do you know why if I use f1(np.pi/2) it substitutes cos(t_1) as 6.123*10**-17. How do I make it substitute zero?

Comment: You use `sp.pi` instead

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks again. :)