# Sympy: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos' for layered functions

Tags: python, jupyter, sympy

### Summary

I have a Jupyter-Lab notebook that I've been trying to use to develop the Jacobian of a robotic arm symbolically with Sympy. I have expressions that are then used in subsequent expressions, and so forth. I receive the message **'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'** when attempting to run the lambdified final expression

### What I've tried

Following the other questions such as

[Sympy to numpy causes the AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'cos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753260/sympy-to-numpy-causes-the-attributeerror-symbol-object-has-no-attribute-cos)

[What causes this error (AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos') in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640759/what-causes-this-error-attributeerror-mul-object-has-no-attribute-cos-in)

I've made sure to call sympy using:

```py
import sympy as sp
```

And then calling everything with the `sp` prefix:

```py
sp.cos()
sp.pi
```

This is my code (I apologize for the long bits)

```py
# symbolic analysis
import sympy as sp

# Variables
theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6 = sp.symbols('theta1 theta2 theta3 theta4 theta5 theta6')
# Constants (undecided)
a1, a2, a3 = sp.symbols('a1 a2 a3')
d1, d4, d6 = sp.symbols('d1 d4 d6')
# Constants (predetermined)
d2, d3, d5, a4, a5, a6, alpha2, alpha6 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
alpha1, alpha3, alpha5 = (sp.pi/2,)*3
alpha4 = -sp.pi/2

# rotation around x
def rotx(angle):
    return sp.Matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, sp.cos(angle), -sp.sin(angle), 0], [0, sp.sin(angle), sp.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# rotation around y
def roty(angle):
    return sp.Matrix([[sp.cos(angle), 0, sp.sin(angle), 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [-sp.sin(angle), 0, sp.cos(angle), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# rotation around z
def rotz(angle):
    return sp.Matrix([[sp.cos(angle), -sp.sin(angle), 0, 0], [sp.sin(angle), sp.cos(angle), 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Translation in either x, y or z
def trans(x,y,z):
    return sp.Matrix([[1, 0, 0, x], [0, 1, 0, y], [0, 0, 0, z], [0, 0, 0, 1]])

def dh_matrix(d, theta, a, alpha):
    return trans(0,0,d)*rotz(theta)*trans(a,0,0)*rotx(alpha)

t_0_1 = dh_matrix(d1, theta1, a1, alpha1)
t_1_2 = dh_matrix(d2, theta2, a2, alpha2)
t_2_3 = dh_matrix(d3, theta3, a3, alpha3)
t_3_4 = dh_matrix(d4, theta4, a4, alpha4)
t_4_5 = dh_matrix(d5, theta5, a5, alpha5)
t_5_6 = dh_matrix(d6, theta6, a6, alpha6)
t_0_6 = t_0_1 * t_1_2 * t_2_3 * t_3_4 * t_4_5 * t_5_6

last_column = t_0_6.col(-1)
x = last_column.row(0)
y = last_column.row(1)
z = last_column.row(2)

# Partial derivatives of x
dxd1 = sp.diff(x,theta1)
dxd2 = sp.diff(x,theta2)
dxd3 = sp.diff(x,theta3)
dxd4 = sp.diff(x,theta4)
dxd5 = sp.diff(x,theta5)
dxd6 = sp.diff(x,theta6)
# Partial derivates of y
dyd1 = sp.diff(y,theta1)
dyd2 = sp.diff(y,theta2)
dyd3 = sp.diff(y,theta3)
dyd4 = sp.diff(y,theta4)
dyd5 = sp.diff(y,theta5)
dyd6 = sp.diff(y,theta6)
# Partial derivates of z
dzd1 = sp.diff(z,theta1)
dzd2 = sp.diff(z,theta2)
dzd3 = sp.diff(z,theta3)
dzd4 = sp.diff(z,theta4)
dzd5 = sp.diff(z,theta5)
dzd6 = sp.diff(z,theta6)

jacobian = sp.Matrix([[dxd1,dxd2,dxd3,dxd4,dxd5,dxd6], [dyd1,dyd2,dyd3,dyd4,dyd5,dyd6], [dzd1,dzd2,dzd3,dzd4,dzd5,dzd6]])
jacobian_numeric = sp.lambdify([theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5,theta6,a1,a2,a3,d1,d4,d6],jacobian)
jacobian_numeric(0,sp.pi/2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.3,0.1)
```

### Expected Output

A 3x6 matrix containing numeric values

### Actual Output

The following error attributed to the final line:

> AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'

I figure it has to do with how I have functions and multiple expressions all twisted together, but I'm not quite sure how to go about founding where exactly it's failing.

### Traceback

It's kind of gigantic; I cut out the rest of the expression with `...`

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d0f45c1787c2> in <module>
----> 1 current_jacobian = jacobian_numeric(0,sp.pi/2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.3,0.1) # add pi/2 to theta2 because of the initial offset between x_2 and x_3
      2 current_jacobian

<lambdifygenerated-1> in _lambdifygenerated(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, a1, a2, a3, d1, d4, d6)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, theta5, theta6, a1, a2, a3, d1, d4, d6):
----> 2     return (array([[array([[-a1*sin(theta1) - a2*sin(theta1)*cos(theta2) + a3*sin(theta1)*sin(theta2)*sin(theta3) - a3*sin(theta1)*cos(theta2)*cos(theta3) +...

AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'cos'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add the traceback?

Comment: Added traceback to the initial question, minus the rest of the expression that I cut off with `...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use `lambdify` to create an executable function, you are no longer in the 'symbolic math' world of `sympy`, and have to pass in numeric values, not symbolic ones.

You can either pass in the  from `numpy` as `np.pi` (as you noted in BenT's answer), or you can numerically evaluate the  from `sympy` as `sp.N(sp.pi)`.  The `N` function converts a symbolic value into a numeric one, including values like .

Comment: This provides an identical "what" to @BenT, but provides a very appreciated "why". Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure why, but when I replace `sp.pi` with `np.pi` in the last line of the code `jacobian_numeric(0,np.pi/2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.3,0.1)` the error goes away. I have seen a couple other questions with similar problems but no good answer at this point. This could be a bug in `simpy` or hopefully someone else has a better explanation.

Comment: Wow, that's incredibly simple, thanks! I wonder if it's because, once `lambdify`-ed, only numeric values should be provided as arguments to the expression `jacobian_numeric`, whereas `sp.pi` is symbolic

Comment: A numpy array with symbols will have object dtype.  `np.cos` delegates the calculation to the `cos` method of each object.